# How to run older version Symfony(2/3) in Homestead?

Tags: symfony, vagrant, homestead

Hey Guys I'm new to the Vagrant. I'm running successfully Symfony4 but not Symfony 2.8.

When running Symfony 2.8 project i.e., Symfony-Demo1.test in browser I get the following:

```
We can’t connect to the server at www.symfony-demo1.test
```

Homestead.yaml

```
folders:
- map: C:\homestead
  to: /home/vagrant/homestead
```

sites:

```
- map: Symfony-Demo.test
  to: /home/vagrant/homestead/Symfony-Demo/public
  type: symfony4

- map: Symfony-Demo1.test    
  to: /home/vagrant/homestead/Symfony-Demo1/web
  type: symfony
```

Host

```
192.168.10.10       Symfony-Demo.test
192.168.10.10       Symfony-Demo1.test
```

Comment: You should check the logs.

Comment: How to check Logs??

Comment: By default in `var/logs` or `app/logs` for Symfony 2